# What does V(L) stand for in Translators?

Tags: terminology, level-translation

This may be an easy question, but I do not understand why Maxim uses the letter "L" within the second supply voltage for [MAX13046E](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX13046E-MAX13047E.pdf). Other manufacturers like TI and NXP use names such as VCC(A), VCC(B) and Vref1, Vref2 in reference to Translators/Level Shifters.

I've searched Maxims glossary to determine the "L" callout with no luck. I am guessing it represents "Logic," "Level," or something as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It signifies "low".  It's Maxim's way of clarifying which is the higher-voltage side and which is the lower-voltage side of the level shifter.

Answer (score 1):

1) User bitsmack is correct about the "low".

2) If you are shopping for I2C parts, you might want to consider cheaper parts, such as ON NLSX4373 or NXP_PCA9507.  The nice thing about these parts is either side can be any voltage, unlike many parts where one side must be at a lower voltage than the other side.

Answer (score 0):

It signifies the voltage level (L for level)